# Applying intersect for each row in different matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have two big matrices and I would like to perform an intersect operation between each row of these matrices. I would get something like that:

```
a =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

b =

     8     3     4
     1     5     9
     6     7     2

intersect(a,b) =

             8
             5
             2
```

An intersect done for all n rows of A and B not using a for loop. Is it possible?

Comment: What if that `2` in `b` is at `b(3,2)` instead and there's something else at `b(3,3)`? Write a loopy implementation first and then ask to vectorize?

Comment: `a(a==b)` this solves your example as you defined it.

Comment: **⑴** In your question, `a` and `b` are transpose of each other. Will `a` and `b` always be transpose of each other?  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍**⑵** What if the common elements are more than one, what output would you expect then?  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍**⑶** What if there is no common element? what would you put for that row? Would you skip it  or put `NaN` for such a case?

Comment: @Artur thank you for the accept, but you should really check out Divakar's properly vectorized answer, and consider accepting that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`broadcasting/bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
b_mask = squeeze(any(bsxfun(@eq,a,permute(b,[1,3,2])),2));
bt = b.';
out = mat2cell(bt(b_mask'),sum(b_mask,2));
```

Sample run -

```
a =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
b =
     3     8     2     6     1
     5     6     9     0     3
     6     7     1     5     3
out{1} =
     8
     6
     1
out{2} =
     5
     3
out{3} =
     []
```

Please note that this would not *work* for cases with duplicate numbers in a row in `b`, as in those cases it would put out duplicated numbers from `b` in the output. This is probably not the expected one, given that we are performing `intersect` operation that gives unique numbers.

To make it work for duplicate elements, we need to modify the creation of `b_mask`, keeping rest as it is. So, the modified version would look something like this -

```
matches0 = bsxfun(@eq,a,permute(b,[1,3,2]));
[~,maxidx] = max(matches0,[],3);
matches1 = bsxfun(@eq,permute(1:size(b,2),[1,3,2]),maxidx) & matches0;
b_mask = squeeze(any(matches1,2));
```

Sample run -

```
a =
     8     8     1
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
b =
     3     8     1     8     5
     5     6     9     0     3
     6     7     1     5     3
out{1} =
     8
     1
out{2} =
     5
     3
out{3} =
     []
```

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well the limitation is each row to have unique numbers.

Comment: Unique how? I don't get what it's doing, yet:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well, let's say we have two `8's` in first row of `b`, it will put out both `8s` in o/p, whereas with `intersect` I think it puts out unique numbers only.

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem like it:) I tested with OP's test case, with `a(1,3)=8`, this way there should be two matches of `8` in the first line. The output contains only the one. Ah, OK: if `b` *also* has multiple 8's, there can be duplicates indeed.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yup! Cracked it! :) bsxfun all over it now!

Comment: Very nice! I hope OP comes back and flips the tick;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak That wasn't a big deal anyway :) Appreciate the support nevertheless!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: this is a kludgy solution, with only apparent vectorization (but in reality, `arrayfun` is a wrapper around a loop). See the other answer by Divakar for a proper vectorized answer.

---

If your intersections are guaranteed to have equal size in each row, you can use `arrayfun` like this:

```
intersect_array_fun = @(A,B) arrayfun(@(k) intersect(A(k,:),B(k,:)), ...
                                     (1:size(A,1)).');
row_intersects = intersect_array_fun(a,b);
```

This will give you the answer:

```
row_intersects =

     8
     5
     2
```

Note that this will fail if your output from `arrayfun` is non-uniform, i.e. if there are multiple sizes returned by `intersect` for every row. The error looks like this:

```
Error using arrayfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.

Error in @(A,B)arrayfun(@(k)intersect(A(k,:),B(k,:)),1:size(A,1))
```

We can expect this and do instead

```
intersect_array_fun = @(A,B) arrayfun(@(k) intersect(A(k,:),B(k,:)), ...
                                      (1:size(A,1)).');
intersect_cell_fun = @(A,B) arrayfun(@(k) intersect(A(k,:),B(k,:)), ...
                                     (1:size(A,1)).', ...
                                     'uniformoutput',false);

try
    row_intersects = intersect_array_fun(a,b);
catch
    row_intersects = intersect_cell_fun(a,b);
end
```

This will catch the error, and tell `arrayfun` to return `cell` output in case there's a mismatch in the size of the intersects. For your above example the result is

```
row_intersects =

     8
     5
     2
```

but if we change `a(1,3)` to `4`, we get

```
row_intersects = 

    [1x2 double]
    [         5]
    [         2]
```

instead: a column cell array.

This brings us to my last point: your question is of vectorization. You want to achieve all this without a for loop, working simultaneously on every row. Well, my first example might have fooled you, but `arrayfun` is just a wrapper for a loop, and is not more efficient than the equivalent loop. However, my latter example with mismatching row sizes suggests that what you're doing is inherently not vectorizable. Since the output possibly consists of varying-length vectors for each row, you probably can't avoid using a loop.